# Trying to isolate a link from IRC messages

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, bots, irc

I Have an IRC bot I'm working on, and one of the features I would like it to have is to take any link a person posts and use BeautifulSoup to parse that page. Now, I have the bot working, getting the messages people post, etc. But, how would I pull a link from the IRC message? Say someone says this:

Person: Check out http://www.site.com, it's cool!

How would I take the link out and assign it to a variable for later use, without pulling the other parts of the message?

I think it's something to do with regexs, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will indeed need to use regular expressions.

There's a decent article with a regular expression for matching URLs and somewhat of a description of what it's doing at [daring fireball](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls).

You can look at how Django does it [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/html.py#L160).

Finally, Python's regular expression [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) may also be useful.

Comment: Gruber's URL regex was the first thing I thought of too. Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the exact track to finish this. You gave yourself the answer with the last sentence of your question. You will use a regular expression with a capture group to get the url and from there you can parse/grab the page that the user has said in the irc.

This site may be of some use for you: http://www.regular-expressions.info/